# Google website Mobile-friendly Тест с провалами

Tags: javascript, css

Есть [сайт](https://auto4rental.com/), который я максимально пытаюсь оптимизировать под разные устройства. Пока что работаю с главной страницей. С мобильных устройств сайт открывается нормально, но каждый запуск [этого теста](https://search.google.com/test/mobile-friendly?pli=1) выдает разные результаты в основном OTHER ERROR. То может пройти тест идеально то просто его заваливает. ГЛ.странница весит в районе 400-500 кб. загрузка <2 секунды. Одним словом ничего не понятно. Не знаю как исправить все ошибки, так как не понятно от чего они возникают. Можете сами протестировать [этот сайт](https://auto4rental.com/) в [тесте](https://search.google.com/test/mobile-friendly?pli=1). Спасибо заранее!!!

*P.S.* Хостинг от Godaddy в европе. [Тут сайт набирает очень высокие баллы более 90%](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/?hl=RU&url=https%3A%2F%2Fauto4rental.com%2F) и [тут тоже](https://gtmetrix.com/reports/auto4rental.com/yDZ2lE2X)

Answer (score 0):

1. Посмотрите здесь ваши ошибки https://validator.w3.org/ ...
2. Почему я посоветовал этот валидатор ?
3. Краткая информация про сам валидатор Переведено с английского языка.-Служба валидации разметки является валидатором Консорциума World Wide Web, который позволяет пользователям Интернета проверять документы HTML и XHTML на предмет правильной разметки. Проверка правильности разметки является важным шагом к обеспечению технического качества веб-страниц.
4. Консорциум World Wide Web - это Консо́рциум Всеми́рной паути́ны — организация, разрабатывающая и внедряющая технологические стандарты для Всемирной паутины. Основателем и главой консорциума является сэр Тимоти Джон Бернерс-Ли, автор множества разработок в области информационных технологий. инфа взята отсюда 
   https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%83%D0%BC_%D0%92%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9_%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%83%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%8B

Comment: Спасибо посмотрел. Да есть парочка которые я конечно же исправлю. Но решит ли это проблему с google friendly тестом? Мне это важно так как еще работа над SEO

Comment: @ Giorgi Ksovreli извините на прошлых курсах на Вангу я провалил ...

Comment: То-есть вы не сталкивались с google mobile-friendly тестом? Просто тут был конкретный ворос про эту платформу

Comment: @Giorgi Ksovreli  если серьезно я не помню точно но кажется валидатор это стандарт ...

Comment: @Giorgi Ksovreli нет не сталкивался но если решите что валидатору не нравиться это поавысит ваши шансы решит проблему ...

Comment: Только что на валидаторе проверил другой сайт который идеально проходит google mobile-friendly тест. А в валидаторе куча ошибок так что похоже не мой вариант :( вот сайт renton.ge